# Using findOneAndUpdate with varying field values

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I am curious to know if there is a better way to go about updating field values. The field values I use sometimes will be there and sometimes will not be, depending on the type of post the user is creating:

**Here is my code to bield out the fields that are to be added to the database**

```
switch (req.body.postType) {
      case "text":
        postFields = {
          postType: "text",
          postBody: req.body.postBody
        };
        break;
      case "video":
        postFields = {
          postType: "video",
          postTitle: req.body.postTitle,
          postBody: req.body.postBody,
          video: {
            ...req.files["postVideo"][0],
            thumbnail: { ...req.files["postVideoThumbnail"][0] }
          }
        };
        break;
      case "photo":
        postFields = {
          postType: "photo",
          postTitle: req.body.postTitle,
          postBody: req.body.postBody,
          photo: {
            ...req.files["postPhoto"][0]
          }
        };
        break;
      case "document":
        postFields = {
          postType: "document",
          postTitle: req.body.postTitle,
          postBody: req.body.postBody,
          document: {
            ...req.files["postDocument"][0]
          }
        };
        break;
      default:
        return res.status(400).json({
          Error:
            "Incorrect postType sent to server. Must be: text, video, photo"
        });
    }
```

After I build this out I then use `findOneAndUpdate` as follows

```
 Feed.findOneAndUpdate(
              { school: req.user.school },
              {
                $push: {
                  posts: postFields
                }
              },
              { new: true }
            )
```

Is there a better way to create the field values?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this since you already are using ES6:

```
let { postType, postBody, postTitle } = req.body  // <-- de-structure
let postFields = {
    postType,
    postBody,
    postTitle,  // <-- no title for text?
    ...(type === 'video' ? { video: {...req.files["postVideo"][0], thumbnail: { ...req.files["postVideoThumbnail"][0]}}} : {}),
    ...(type === 'photo' ? { photo: { ...req.files["postPhoto"][0]}} : {}),
    ...(type === 'document' ? { document: {...req.files["postDocument"][0]}} : {}),
}
```

if `text` has no title then just use the same approach as the `video` etc where you use the [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) and if type is `text` just add the title via spreading an object with the title ...

Basically the idea is to use spread with a ternary operator to conditionally decorate an object with properties.